# Covariance of two distinct quadratic forms

Tags: nonparametric, covariance, quadratic-form

Let's say that I have two random vectors, that should belong to the same distribution family, but are distinct. I.e.

$\mathbf{Y_{1}} = (Y_{11}, ..., Y_{n1})^{T} \sim D(\mu_1, \Sigma_1)$

and

$\mathbf{Y_{2}} =  (Y_{12}, ..., Y_{n2})^{T} \sim D(\mu_2, \Sigma_2)$

where $D$ just means some n-dimensional multivariate distribution. Let's say I have $\mathbf{\Gamma_1, \Gamma_2}$ s.t.

$$
R_1 = \mathbf{Y_1^T\Gamma_1Y_1}
$$

is a quadratic form and

$$
R_2= \mathbf{Y_2^T\Gamma_2Y_2}
$$

is also a quadratic form.

Are there any general results for $Cov(R_1, R_2)$?. That is, without specifying the underlying distribution of the y's, is there any general result I can find? $R_1 \not\perp R_2$

Comment: Can you say something about the relationship between your $Y$-vectors, such as all the cross-moments?